# Powershell script on VM as scheduled task

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I wrote a simple script to move files that contain a specific substring in the file name from one folder to another.

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\source" -Filter *.xlsm                        
$Target = "C:\target"                                           

$substring = 'copy'                                     

foreach ($file in $Source) {                                    
    if($file.Name -match $substring){                           
        Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $Target -Force      
    }
        }
```

I want to automate it on VM. It works fine when I'm running it manually and  via task scheduler when I'm logged in VM, however when I switch to 'run whether logged on or logged off' in task scheduler (script properties) it won't work. I run it with following parameters:

`-noprofile -executionpolicy unrestricted -noninteractive -file "path to my script"`

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the history tab show? (Enable history if you haven’t)

Comment: turn on transcription and set it to a location that the account in use can write to. then run the task and see what you get ... [*grin*]

Comment: @DougMaurer history tab actually shows: created task process --> task started --> action started --> action completed --> task completed. So I guess this is the expected outcome however script did not do the job.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the source and target folders are on network drive so I guess this may be the issue.

Comment: Mapped drives dont exist unless the user is logged in. Additionally the user running the task has to have full rights on both source/destination.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey with 'run whether the user is logged on or not' option ticked, powershell window won't even appear on the screen. I also added Start-Transcript -Path 'same_folder_as_script' as a first line in my script file but nothing is being created.

Comment: @Scepticalist makes sense... it works ok when I end the remote session with the VM so I guess I would need to stay connected to a VPN. The question is - can the laptop be in 'sleep'?

Comment: @KingWolin - if the user is not logged in, the task runs as `system`. that means the code is NOT running interactively ... and there is no UI presented anywhere. ///// if you need a UI to be running, you will need to create a user account to run the task ... and will need to run any needed software AS that account at least once before the task tries to use that account - otherwise "things" won't be properly initialized.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I don't mind the script being executed 'in the backgroud'. This is a company VM and we use Egnyte for file sharing, security etc. so I think this is a problem here. I've done couple tests recently and it worked fine with laptop in 'sleep' mode however I guess there is a timeout so it can be too long, otherwise it will disconnect completely and then there is a problem with mapped drive access.

Comment: @KingWolin - it seems you will need to create an account to run the code. that is fairly common .. use one of your service accounts OR make a new one just for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

When the option "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected, the scheduled task runs on a different session.

This means that it does not have access to the mapped network drives !.

So, you need to either map drives in your script or use the fully qualified name (i.e., \server name\share name)

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45118323/1689226) as well